# Counting consecutive repeats, and returning the maximum value in each in each string of repeats if over a threshold

Tags: r

I am working with long strings of repeating 1's and 0's representing the presence of a phenomenon as a function of depth. If this phenomenon is flagged for over 1m, it is deemed significant enough to use for further analyses, if not it could be due to experimental error.

I ultimately need to get a total thickness displaying this phenomenon at each location (if over 1m).

In a dummy data set the input and expected output would look like this:

```
#Depth from 0m to 10m with 0.5m readings
depth <- seq(0, 10, 0.5)

#Phenomenon found = 1, not = 0
phenomflag <- c(1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0)
```

What I would like as an output is a vector with: 4, 5 (which gets converted back to 2m and 2.5m)

I have attempted to solve this problem using

```
y <- rle(phenomflag)
z <- y$length[y$values ==1]
```

but once I have my count, I have no idea how to:

a) Isolate 1 maximum number **from each group** of consecutive repeats.

b) Restrict to consecutive strings longer than (x) - this might be easier after a.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why gets converted back to 2 and 2.5? Isn't it 1.5 and 2m?

Comment: Each measurement is a 0.5m interval. The only repeating series longer than 1 m (two  1's in a row) are the four and five consecutive 1's. 2 and 2.5 comes from 4/2 and 5/2

Comment: `sort(y$lengths[y$values==1], T)[1:2]` you looking for?

Comment: `x <- cbind(y$lengths,y$values)` `;`  `x[which(x[,1]>=3 & x[,2]==1)]`

Comment: count's solution worked out for me, thanks a ton for the help!

Answer (score 0):

count posted a good solution in the comments section.

```
 y <- y <- rle(repeating series of 1's and 0's)

 x <- cbind(y$lengths,y$values) ; x[which(x[,1]>=3 & x[,2]==1)]
```

This results in just the values that repeat more than a threshold of 2, and just the maximum.